# Sum if Returning Zero

Tags: excel-formula

In my spreadsheet im trying to Sum based on criteria from an adjacent cell. The formula I have is

```
=SUMIF(Table2[[#Headers],[Material Type]],
       "Silver Bearing",
       Table2[[#Headers],[Settlement Amount]])
```

This seems to be correct, but it returns a zero. Any Ideas?

Comment: remove the `[#Headers],` you are literally trying to sum the headers not the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula, but I recommend you use SUMIFS as it's more dynamic and scalable than the singular. Your issue is you're summing the headers where you need the `DataBodyRange`. Another consideration is to confirm "Silver Bearing" is the *exact* spelling and punctuation.

`=SUMIF(Table2[Material Type],"Silver Bearing",Table2[Settlement Amount])`

`=SUMIFS(Table2[Settlement Amount],Table2[Material Type],"Silver Bearing")`

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I Figured it out. I was under the impression that I could just click on the header to choose the column, but i needed to actually scroll down to select the range.

Comment: There is a specific spot on the header you can click where it will select the databodyrange of that column, it is a pretty small area to click though.